# How to enter number of rows and columns, and create a table

Tags: javascript, html, parameters, html-table, onclick

I'm still taking HTML lessons, but I managed to do this last week and now I've completely forgotten the answer.

Basically there are two inputs. In one, you enter the number of columns, and the other, the number of rows. When you press a button it creates a table with those in mind (contents of the table don't matter). I'm supposed to use parameters in a function but I forgot a little how they work, and this is the mess that I ended up with:
I'm pretty sure that everything excluding the parameters part is right. I just don't know how to get the values from the input texts and use them as parameters.

```
<html>
<head> <title> Rows and Columns </title> </head>
<body>

<form name="form">

Number of rows: <input type="text" name="row" />
Number of columns: <input type="text" name="col" />
<input type="button" onClick="create(c,r)" value="create" />



</form>


<script>


function create(c,r) {
    c=document.forms.form.col.value
    r=document.forms.form.row.value
    document.write("<table width='1'>" + 
    for(i=1;i<=r;i++) { document.write("<tr>" + 
        for(e=1;e<=c;e++) { document.write("<td>" + c + "</td>") } + "</tr>") } + "</table>")





</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass values when you are calling the onClick like this:

`<input type="button" onClick="create(document.forms.form.col.value, document.forms.form.row.value)" value="create" />`

remove these from create function

```
c=document.forms.form.col.value
r=document.forms.form.row.value
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I tried to use similar kind of code; but it don't seem to work.

```js
 function create(c,r) {
            document.write("<table width='1'>" + 
            for(i=1;i<=r;i++) { document.write("<tr>" + 
                for(e=1;e<=c;e++) { document.write("<td>" + c + "</td>") } + "</tr>") } + "</table>")
```

```html
<form name="form">
                    <input type="button" onClick="create(document.forms.form.col.value, document.forms.form.row.value)" value="create" />
                </form>
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32142587)